# Dynamic factor model for inflation (UIG)

Tags: econometrics, inflation, applied-econometrics, federal-reserve

I'm trying to replicate some results of Fed Underlying Inflation Gauge (UIG) model, which is a dynamic factor model to capture inflation trend.  https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/policy/underlying-inflation-gauge

I'm getting some not so good results. The following figure shows the UIG results while my is a lot smoother.

[image]

I'm trying to investigate the reason. One difference is that I used a dynamic factor model in statsmodels package in Python, which has the static format as following:
$\begin{align}
y_t^i & = \Lambda^i f_t + u_t^i \\
f_t & = A_1 f_{t-1} + \dots + A_p f_{t-p} + \eta_t \qquad \eta_t \sim N(0, I)\\
u_t^i & = \varepsilon_t^i \qquad \varepsilon_t^i \sim N(0, \Sigma)
\end{align}$

But the UIG is actually doing something like:

$\begin{align}
y_t^i & = \sum_{h}\beta_h^i f_{t-h} + u_t^i \\
u_t^i & = \varepsilon_t^i \qquad \varepsilon_t^i \sim N(0, \Sigma)
\end{align}$

Could this cause a problem?